# Can't figure out how to combine a callback and an anonymous function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new in Typescript and I'm having a problem with combining multiple callbacks and an anonymous function. I'm working on expanding an already existing project and I'm following the lead of the previous person who worked on this, but I have no problem with changing the method's structure if needed.

So I call getAnimals(), and I should be getting the animals array back, but instead I get nothing back, it doesn't even go in the if condition of queryFunction. If I put a callback right outside the if condition, the program executes the callback(allAnimals), but then I understandably get a "Can't send headers after they are sent to the client" error.

```js
 class Service {

        public getAnimals(con: any, callback: (animals: Animal[]) => any) {

            var queryFunction = (query: string, args: any[], callback: (a: Animal[]) => any) => {
                var allAnimals = [];
                connection.query(query, args, (err, data) => {
                    err && console.error(err);
                    if (data.length != 0) {
                        allAnimals = <Animal[]>data;
                        console.log(allAnimals);
                        callback(allAnimals);
                    }
                });
                /* callback(allAnimals); this gives me a response but 
                the array is empty so it's not the response I want*/
            }

            var query1: string = "insert sql query here";
            var args = ["args1", "args2"];
            queryFunction(query1, args, (dogs: Dog[]) => {
                var query2: string = "insert sql query here";
                args = ["args3", "args4"];
                queryFunction(query2, args, (cats: Cat[]) => {
                    var animals: Animal[] = [...dogs,...cats];
                    callback(animals);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm probably setting up the queryFunction wrong or I'm utilizing the callback functions wrong, but I can't seem to get it right. I would appreciate some advice. Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you rename the function? Aren’t actually an accessor in typescript?

Comment: @NicklasPouey-Winger you mean the get one? That's not the name I use in my project, I wrote it this way without thinking, but I didn't know that "get" already had a use in typescript. I've updated the code I provided, thanks!

Comment: What is `condition`? Where is it defined and what does it contain?

Comment: @wvteijlingen I updated my code to show what `condition` is. I know for a fact that `data.length > 0` because when I use the callback that is in the comments and disable the other callback, `data` gets printed at my console. But when I run the code as is, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Your function declarations still seem a little wonky. I think you're missing a brace at the end here: `getAnimals(con: any, callback: (animals: Animal[]) => any)` and `var queryFunction = (query: string, args: any[], callback: (a: Animal[])`.